# Listen for the statement until it's true

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, listener, jquery-events

I'm looking for the solution to my problem with image upload. I have one script that is kind of compressing my files with Javascript. Then it creates an Array with results in base64 which I want to add to my page as an `<input type="hidden">`. I have just one problem. It takes a bit to compress these images and `.change()` event on file input is not enough. Because it begins before the compression is done.

I was thinking about adding something like event listener for the statement, something like:

```
if(result_base64.length != input.files.length){
    listen
} else {
    do the function
}
```

Is it possible to achieve that without setting the interval function?

The compression script:

```
var result_base64 = [];
var images = document.getElementById('images');
var max_width = images.getAttribute('data-maxwidth');
var max_height = images.getAttribute('data-maxheight');

images.onchange = function(){
    if ( !( window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob ) ) {
        alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
        return false;
    }
    readfiles(images.files);
}

function readfiles(files) {
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        processfile(files[i]);
    }
    images.value = "";
}

function processfile(file) {
    if( !( /image/i ).test( file.type ) ){
        alert( "File "+ file.name +" is not an image." );
        return false;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var blob = new Blob([event.target.result]);
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = blobURL;
        image.onload = function() {
            result_base64.push(resizeMe(image));
        }
    };
}

function resizeMe(img) {
    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    var width = img.width;
    var height = img.height;

    if (width > height) {
        if (width > max_width) {
            height = Math.round(height *= max_width / width);
            width = max_width;
        }
    } else {
        if (height > max_height) {
            width = Math.round(width *= max_height / height);
            height = max_height;
        }
    }
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, width, height);
    return canvas.toDataURL("image/jpeg",0.7);
}
```

Comment: Append the hidden input at the end of your compressing script.

Comment: I have no access to compressing script, that's the problem :/

Comment: there is no functionality that would let you wait for a certain condition to become true (assuming the condition is affected by an asynchronous action), the better option would be to find a way to receive a notification when the compression is complete.

Comment: Could you please tell us how do you call the compression function. Does the compression function return a promise?

Comment: surely it has some kind of callback or promise, without it it wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: the compression script is in the question now. Maybe you can suggest some edits so I can suggest them to the "owner". I'm not the best one in js :/

Comment: It's definitely possible to give it a callback, it just isn't necessarily easy. It would need to count how many images are done being processed, and when that count matches the total, trigger an event. The alternative would be to promisify the process function and use promise.all and [].map. both cases may take a bit of reorganizing.

Comment: OK. Thank you. I'll try to get access to the script and maybe I'll learn something new. Do you have some easy documentations for promises maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Then it creates an Array with results in base64

In processFile() you can fire an event like

```
function processfile(file) {
    if( !( /image/i ).test( file.type ) ){
        alert( "File "+ file.name +" is not an image." );
        return false;
    }
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
    reader.onload = function (event) {
        var blob = new Blob([event.target.result]);
        window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
        var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = blobURL;
        image.onload = function() {
            result_base64.push(resizeMe(image));
            $(window).trigger('filesCompressed', result_base64); // This is the addition
        }
    };
```

}

Where you need these files, you can listen for this event like

```
$(window).on('filesCompressed', function(e, files) {
   // Do something with files
 })
```

Catch: The listening code must execute before the event is triggered.

Comment: As Kavin said. The only thing I need is to know when the Array is ready so I can fire the events I need.

Comment: and to add, with the update, at this point all you would have to do is count how many times the event is triggered and compare that to the total files.

Comment: That is what I was looking for. Thank you guys.